# flutter : how to know whether argument is passed or not while navigator

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

here is my basic code for argument demo in flutter navigator

I have created this simple example to make my problem explain

here two button , one for add and other for edit

while clicking on add I am not passing argument
while clicking on edit I am passing string id ( like clicking on product and passing product id to next page)

while adding or editing I want to navigate same page

here my question is how to know argument is passed or not in next page

some suggested to pass argument while adding...but its not solution

I don't want to pass any argument while add

here is basic code

```
class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {

  static const routname='productpage';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final arg=ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Product management sCreen'),),
      body: Text(arg!=null?'Edit Mode':'Add Mode'),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('HomeScreen'),),
      body: Center(child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
          TextButton(onPressed: (){
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ProductPage.routname);
          }, child: Text('Add Product')),
          TextButton(onPressed: (){
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ProductPage.routname,arguments: '1');
            }, child: Text('Edit Product')),

        ],),
      ),),
    );
  }
```

I am getting red screen while clicking on add
showing error

> "null is not a subtype of type String"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `!` use `?` to accept nullable data.  If you are sure that you will get string or null use

```dart
 final String? arg=ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?;
```

Now you can check

```dart
if (arg == null) {

} else {...}
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked...and is it good approach to remove typecast Like I have changed to ``` final arg=ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments```

Comment: yes, `as` prefix was forcing to make it string instead of nullable string. Also you can do is check for different data type

Answer (score 1):

For Getx users:

You can find whether the key exists before getting the value

```
bool get isKeyExists = Get.arguments != null &&
      Get.arguments is Map &&
      (Get.arguments as Map).containsKey('myNewKey');
```